# Extending UITextField Control in iOS Development

Tags: ios

I am creating a custom UITextField which is responsible for ensuring that the user only enters numeric data into the TextField. I want to capture the following event inside the custom textbox.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
```

How can I do that?

**UPDATE 1:**

// the below code sets the delegate but the delegate methods never gets called

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a question?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You will need to provide more information to get help.

Comment: updated with more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your `MyTextBox.h` add the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol

on your `MyTextBox` initialization code, add:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

Comment: If I MyTextBox inherits from UITextField then do I still need the UITextFieldDelegate protocol

Comment: Yes, you need to implement the `UITextFieldDelegateProtocol` in your text box's implementation file (MyTextBox.m) after adorning it to your interface's declaration per Ismael's answer.

Comment: Just did that but shouldChangeCharactersInRange is not triggered!

Comment: I am assigning the delegate inside the initWithCoder method since I created UITextField using Interface Builder.

Comment: Inside initWithCoder the self.delegate is nil.

Comment: I assigned the delegate inside the UIViewController and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at the office so I couldn't respond to your doubts. I'm glad it helped! :)